# Java environment-specific properties WITHOUT Spring

Tags: java, groovy, properties

Spring has made it so incredibly easy to set up application properties...but how would you do it without Spring?

I need to deploy a Java / Groovy application to a server where using Spring is out of the question... and I also don't have the liberty to install anything like Redis either. One option I am considering is to set up a Spring Cloud Config Server elsewhere and have my application consume properties from the config server. Trouble is, that is a bit of an overkill for my project now.

Could anyone suggest a way to do this in good, old, plain Java? :)

Comment: Use class [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) to load a `*.properties` file.

Comment: Pass an environment variable, and depending on its value, load one or another properties file?

Comment: Can you bundle a properties file in your .jar, or do you plan to change the properties after deploying?

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you for the suggestion! The part that I am struggling with though, is to find a place to put that value which determines the environment for the application. I do not have the freedom to set any environment variables on the server to which I am deploying.

Comment: @VGR I need to bundle my properties in the .jar. I won't be able to change the properties after deploying

Comment: Groovy configslurper?

Comment: @QingXia put it in an env.properties file that you load first?

Comment: @JBNizet hmm true. But that means I would need a different env.properties file for different environments. You are right though, that's about the only option since I have no rights on the server. Thanks for your advice, much appreciated! :)

Comment: @tim_yates: oh yeah, that's cool. will surely make the code less verbose with the Groovy ConfigSlurper.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple and basic example, but you can modify it as you like:

**PropertyConfigurator.java**

```
public class PropertiesConfigurator
{

    Properties properties = new Properties();

    String configInputPath = null;

    InputStream configInputStream = null;



    public PropertiesConfigurator(String configInputPath)
    {
        this.configInputPath = configInputPath;
    }



    public PropertiesConfigurator load() throws IOException, PropertyException
    {
        try
        {

            this.configInputStream = new FileInputStream(this.configInputPath);

            // load a properties file
            this.properties.load(this.configInputStream);

            validate();

        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed load properties file: " + this.configInputPath);
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (PropertyException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("One or more properties are empty");
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (this.configInputStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.configInputStream.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("Failed to close input stream");
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }

        return this;
    }



    private void validate() throws PropertyException
    {
        Enumeration<?> e = this.properties.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements())
        {
            String key = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value = this.properties.getProperty(key);

            if (value.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println(String.format("Property %s is empty!", key));
                throw new PropertyException("One or more properties are empty");
            }
        }
    }



    public String getProperty(String key)
    {
        return this.properties.getProperty(key);
    }



    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PropertiesConfigurator))
            return false;

        PropertiesConfigurator that = (PropertiesConfigurator) o;

        if (properties != null ? !properties.equals(that.properties) : that.properties != null)
            return false;
        if (configInputPath != null ? !configInputPath.equals(that.configInputPath) : that.configInputPath != null)
            return false;
        return configInputStream != null ?
                configInputStream.equals(that.configInputStream) :
                that.configInputStream == null;

    }



    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = properties != null ? properties.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (configInputPath != null ? configInputPath.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (configInputStream != null ? configInputStream.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

**PropertyException.java**

```
public class PropertyException extends Exception
{
    public PropertyException()
    {
    }



    public PropertyException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }



    public PropertyException(String message, Throwable throwable)
    {
        super(message, throwable);
    }
}
```

**MainRunner.java**

```
public class MainRunner
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            String configFilePath = "application.properties";
            PropertiesConfigurator propertiesConfigurator = new PropertiesConfigurator(configFilePath).load();

            String prop1 = propertiesConfigurator.getProperty("keyprop1");

            // Do whatever you want with prop1
            // ...
        }

        catch (PropertyException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Failed to load properties");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in main application");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example of application.properties**

```
keyprop1=value1
keyprop2=value2
```

Again, it's very basic and you should definitely improve this code and add your logic, validation, etc.

Comment: Thank you Avihoo for the quick response. It is a great example. :) I will definitely use it in my project. I am still trying to figure out the part where environment can be determined though. Don't know how people lived before Spring... LOL

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://constretto.org. That's easy to use configuration framework.