# Best practice to store resources(mainly strings) to test application at different modes

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

I need to test application in different modes, some application behaviour will be the same at both, and some is not(for example different texts or locators).

So how I see it now:

1. There is property which define which mode we are testing now
2. There are a lot of different property files, which contains expected messages and etc
3. Property from step 1 will define to which property file we should go for expected value

But I can't remember or create any good solution how to use this values from property in tests, only create class per property file with public static final constants.

Can you give me an advice and/or any link to existing code which do such things?

Comment: if your in a spring-environment https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.0.M1/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html could be useful.

Comment: Nope, I don't use spring

Comment: nevertheless: if you use "real plain java", have a look at the principle of Spring profiles (passing the profile via enviroment-variable and then using the value for e.g. loading properties). I think this shouldn't be too complicated to implement this principle and adpot it to your use case.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862397/java-environment-specific-properties-without-spring
could maybe help.

Comment: Thank you for example of how to go to different property files, but the issue how to use this values is still exist. I believe there are better way than public static final fields

Comment: maybe I need a better understanding of your problem: why not load the properties into a  `HashMap` and then iterate over the map without generating any boiler-plate classes with static constants?
I think we need some code example from your side for better help.

Comment: The final point of usage property's values will be in tests and look like this:

...some preconditions
Assert.assertEquals(actualMessage, expectedMessageFromProperty)

I don't think Assert.assertEquals(actualMessage, map.get(expectedMessageFromPropertyKey)); looks pretty and readable.

for example 
Assert.assertEquals(actualMessage, ExpectedNotifications.deleteNotification) looks prettier

Comment: #1 in 100% of the Assert-Impl I know it is: assert(expected, actual). please check that on your side.
#2 still don't have your point. In both cases (map or any kind of static field) you will have redirection to the "really expected" value. I you want see really the expected "STRINGS" in your code: You have to write everything more than once *OR* introduce a kind of code generation. There are many tools and principles for code generation (e.g. some simply adoptable in java/maven).

Comment: My point is how to use this values from property.
Your suggestion is map. Why I need a map if I can do the same just with property reader?

What the difference between assert(expected, propertyMap.get("property.key")) and assert(expected, propertyReader.getProperty("property.key"))?

The only advantage I see is that read property each time is heavier than load it once at map and getting from there. But I'm pretty sure there are should better way, than just duplicate values from property into some map/constant fields

Comment: on that point: I have no idea, what you try to achhieve. sorry, I can't help you.